# How can I copy my hard disk to a RAID 10 array?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-10

I would like to create a RAID 10 array on my PC. But since my target hard disk was purchased some time ago and there are newer models in the market, I want to create an array from brand new hard disks and than copy the target hard drive (that has games and softwares installed in it).

Is it possible to copy my drive into an empty RAID 10 array. How do I do that safely and in the shortest way?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your RAID10 is hardware based, then any disk imaging software will work.  [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is popular.

Answer (score -1):

Just use software to clone your data to a new drive like said above. From there create your RAID. Ideally you want to use the same disks in your RAID, so buy 2 or more new hard disks (depending on how many disk you want in your RAID10), clone your data from the old disk to the new disk using free or paid software, then be done with it.

It would be possible to just include your old hard disk in the RAID and just mirror it to get the data over and then remove it from the RAID, but the hard disks would need to have the same sector size.

Comment: Be wary of different sector sizes.